# XML to flatten CSV/JSON conversion using XSL

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I'm trying to create a CSV file from the XML file. Here XML can have multiple child/parent tags. These tags are not fixed. It will be dynamic.
Input XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <emp_id>123</emp_id>
            <emp_name>john</emp_name>
            <emp_type>permanent</emp_type>
            <addresses>
                <address>
                    <flat_no>23</flat_no>
                    <street>Ville Street</street>
                    <state>California</state>
                    <country>USA</country>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <flat_no>24</flat_no>
                    <street>Parlour Street</street>
                    <state>New York</state>
                    <country>USA</country>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <flat_no>25</flat_no>
                    <street>Parle Street</street>
                    <state>Canada</state>
                    <country>USA</country>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <flat_no>26</flat_no>
                    <street>Ville Parle Street</street>
                    <state>New Jersey</state>
                    <country>USA</country>
                </address>
                <address>
                    <flat_no>27</flat_no>
                    <street>Parle Ville Street</street>
                    <state>San Jose</state>
                    <country>USA</country>
                </address>
            </addresses>
            <salary>
                <pay_scale>Manager</pay_scale>
                <tax_id>12345</tax_id>
            </salary>
        </employee>
    </employees>
```

Example output should be as below:

**employee.csv** should have below columns and data:

```
emp_id,emp_name,emp_type
123,john,permanent
```

**address.csv** should have below columns and data:

```
emp_id,emp_name,emp_type,flat_no,street,state,country,payscale,tax_id
123,john,permanent,23,Ville Street,California,USA,,
123,john,permanent,24,Parlour Street,New York,USA,,
123,john,permanent,25,Parle Street,Canada,USA,,
123,john,permanent,26,Ville Parle Street,New Jersey,USA,,
123,john,permanent,27,Parle Ville Street,San Jose,USA,,
```

**salary.csv** should have below columns and data:

```
emp_id,emp_name,emp_type,pay_scale,tax_id
123,john,permanent,Manager,12345
```

It should go like this.
All the child tags(i.e., which are not inside the parent tags) should be in one CSV file and if any parent tags appear then it should go into the other CSV file like address,salary.

As I'm new to this XSLT, I don't know how to do it. What I heard is that **XML <--> XSLT <--> CSV** is faster i.e., XSLT is the one which is suitable for converting very fast.

Note: Tags cab be varied. Given is an example

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There is more than one thread on Stack Overflow that deals with converting XML to CSV with XSLT. Try to go look for one and adapt the code you find to your needs.

Comment: I would like to create an XSLT for the specified scenario. Help would be apprecited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <xsl:result-document href="emp.txt">
            <xsl:value-of select="employee/emp_id/local-name(),employee/emp_name/local-name(),employee/emp_type/local-name()" separator=","/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="employee/emp_id,employee/emp_name,employee/emp_type" separator=","/>
        </xsl:result-document>
        <xsl:for-each select="employee/addresses">
            <xsl:result-document href="address.txt">
                <xsl:value-of select="parent::employee/emp_id/local-name(),parent::employee/emp_name/local-name(),parent::employee/emp_type/local-name(),address[1]/flat_no/local-name(),address[1]/street/local-name(),address[1]/state/local-name(),address[1]/country/local-name()" separator=","/>

                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="address">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::employee/emp_id,ancestor::employee/emp_name,ancestor::employee/emp_type,flat_no,street,state,country" separator=", "/>
                    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="employee">
            <xsl:result-document href="salary.txt">
                <xsl:value-of select="emp_id/local-name(),emp_name/local-name(),emp_type/local-name(),salary/pay_scale/local-name(),salary/tax_id/local-name()" separator=","/>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="emp_id,emp_name,emp_type,salary/pay_scale,salary/tax_id" separator=","/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Check it.

Comment: This looks fine. But, It is pretty much hard-coded. Was there any dynamic way to create the same. I mean all the tag names are hard-coded like the XPath.

Comment: You need to tell us what aspects of your XML are known in advance and what aspects are unknown. Doing a completely general flattening of XML to CSV that works on any XML at all (e.g. where employee has both multiple addresses and multiple assignments) is pretty well impossible.